# Issues returning $q.reject from an $http.error event

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have a login page which submits user credentials to a login controller.
But before authorizing the user, I need to "open" a session and receive a valid sessionID.

My main issue however is handling the error event on the `this.openUserSession` **API** call down below. That is, I'm returning a `$q.reject()` on the `$http.error()` event, but it's not bubbling up the stack as I would expect.

**Here's the flow:**

1) The user enters credentials and clicks the "Login" button, which calls into `LoginCtrl` function `loginUser()`

2)  I immediately call ing `userService.initUserSession` to get a valid sessionID.

3) If successful, then call into `loginService.authUser`
4) If invalid sessionID, then I need to return`$q.reject` and display message 
"Could not open user session"

***** CODE DETAILS *****

Notice that first I "init" the app in `that.initRzr`, then I call `that.openUserSession`  below:

```js
this.initUserSession = function initSession($rootScope, username) {    

var deferred = $q.defer();
deferred.notify("Establishing Session ID...");

$rootScope.userID = username;
var that = this;
this.getRazorInitParams().then(function (razorEnvJson) {
 
 that.initRzr(razorEnvJson).then(function (data) {
  
  if (data.status.match(/SUCCESS/g)) {
   
   // ******** OPEN USER SESSION ***********
   that.openUserSession(razorEnvJson).then(function (data) {
    // ... some code omitted here.
    deferred.resolve(sessionID);
    return sessionID;
   });
  }
 }, function (error) {
               // *** I NEVER HIT LINE !!! ***
  deferred.reject('Could not open user session.');
 });
});
return deferred.promise;
}
```

**** OPEN USER SESSION ***

NOTE: I am hitting the `.error()` code here, as I can see the console logged message "Cannot open a user session via api cal...". However, processing seems to stop here, and my login screen just freezes with the spinner icon.

```js
this.openUserSession = function (razorEnvParams) {
    
 // init some variables here...
 
 var url = "http://" + _domain + ":" + _port + controllerpath + "?userid=" + user + "&pass=" + pass;
 var deferred = $q.defer();
 deferred.notify("Opening user session..."); 
 
 $http({
  method: 'GET',
  encoding: 'JSON',
  headers: {
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'true',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  withCredentials: true,
  url: url
 }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
  deferred.resolve(data);
 }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log("Cannot open a user session via api call. Errors details: " + data);
  deferred.reject("Could not open a user session.");
 });
 return deferred.promise;
}
```

I will try to improve this post if unclear. Please advise...

thanks in advance.

Bob

**** UPDATE ****

As per JB Nizet's answer below, I was missing the error callback of `that.openUserSession` . I added `function(error)` below, and it worked as expected.

I will now move forward with the chaining suggestion JB posted.

```js
this.initUserSession = function initSession($rootScope, username) {       // ESTABLISH A RAGE CONNECTION AND SESSION ID !

var deferred = $q.defer();
deferred.notify("Establishing Rage Session ID...");

var that = this;
this.getRazorInitParams().then(function (razorEnvJson) {

 that.initRazor(razorEnvJson).then(function (data) {
  
  if (data.status.match(/SUCCESS/g)) {
   that.openUserSession(razorEnvJson).then(function (data) {
    
    deferred.resolve(sessionID);
    return sessionID;
   }, function (error) {
    deferred.reject('Could not open user session.');
   });
  }
 }, function (error) {   // **** ADDED ERROR HANDLING ***
  deferred.reject('Could not initial a user session.');
 });
});
return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openUserSession()` fails, and you don't have any error callback for that failure, so the promise is never resolved nor rejected.

This bug, and the large imbrication, is caused by your usage of a [promise antipattern](http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/). Use chaining instead:

```
that.getRazorInitParams()
    .then(that.initRzr)
    .then(that.openUserSession)
    .catch(function() { ... });
```

No need to create a deferred and resolving it. Just use chaining. For example, `openUserSession()` can be replaced by

```
this.openUserSession = function (razorEnvParams) {

    var url = "http://" + _domain + ":" + _port + controllerpath;
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        encoding: 'JSON',
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'true',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        withCredentials: true,
        url: url,
        params: {
            userid: user,
            pass: pass
        }
    }).then(function (response) {       
        return response.data;
    });
}
```

Also, never use a GET to transfer secret credentials: they will end up, in plain text, in all kinds of logs. And never concatenate parameters. They must be encoded, and Angular does that for you by using `params`.

Comment: absolutely agreed re: the GET request. This is still in dev mode, and the security process will be overhauled very soon.

Comment: as you said above. I had no callback. It works now that I've added `function (error)` to `that.openUserSession`. I will also go ahead with re-coding this to adhere to the chaining principle.

Comment: I've used POST for other things as well, so I've just finished converting this GET to a POST. It works if I use `data:{ .. }` , however with `params{..}` I'm having an issue in my c# controller due to my use of the `JObject` - ex/ `public HttpResponseMessage Post(JObject dashboardObj)`. The JObject is basically showing a Null value. I'll create another post for this, as it is a very important change.